D3 event.selection is not working in brush listeners in 5.16.0 version
const brush = d3.brush()
  .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .on('end', brushed);

svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'brush')
  .call(brush);

function brushed(event: any) {
  const selection = event.selection;
  if (!selection) return;
  const [[x0, y0], [x1, y1]] = selection;
  const xDomain = [x.invert(x0), x.invert(x1)];
  const yDomain = [y.invert(y1), y.invert(y0)];
  console.log("xDomain", xDomain);
  console.log("yDomain", yDomain);
}

I created one brush functionality with the existing chart and I tried to capture the event once the brush operation is done, but the event selection is not working in d3 5.16.0 version, But it is working fine in d3 7.0 version. Is there any other approaches in 5.16.0 version to capture the events..?

The event handler used to use a global (d3.event) to access the event, rather than having the event be passed as a parameter. So you could use d3.event.selection, see v6 migration guide on events and brushes.
